# PL/SQL Looping Issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hey I'm trying to take two users inputs, A string and a number so that my stored pl/sql procedure can print to the screen their inputted string in all UPPER case looped to the amount of times of the number they inputted. For example they do exec silly_shout ('hello', 3) It will print HELLO, 3 times. I can successfully create the procedure to print their inputted string in all UPPERCASE but as soon as i try to implement the loop the sqlplus terminal when i start the script gives me the error" 'Procedure created with compliation errors' is anyone able to look at my code to find where the error is coming from?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE silly_shout
(
silly_name IN VARCHAR2,
silly_int IN INT
) AS
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..silly_number
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UPPER(silly_name) || '!!');
    END LOOP;   
END;
/
```

Comment: You can use `show errors` to display more details about the error. But even better, you an IDE such as Oracle SQL Developer to develop stored procedure. It's so much more efficient and comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS CODE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE silly_shout
(
silly_name IN VARCHAR2,
silly_int IN INT
) AS
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..silly_int
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UPPER(silly_name) || '!!');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: @Mohammad Asghari - instead of just handing the OP a solution on a silver platter, you should try to help educate him by explaining what was wrong with his own code.